# Power Query Importing Time Values form Excel in [h]:mm format returns wrong value

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to import a worksheet from an Excel 97-2003 workbook containing a production schedule. The duration of each operation (a row on the spreadsheet) is derived from a formula looking at the quantity * unit rate and is displayed in excel in [h]:mm format.

When importing to power query in the editor the duration values which are imported do not match the original in the worksheet and some are more and some less than the original value from the worksheet and the resulting output table is therefore incorrect.

I've searched for solution online but have failed to find an answer. Can anyone help?

**Image of the Power Query Result and the raw data from the worksheet**

[image: Image of the Power Query Result and the raw data from the worksheet]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem from the information you have provided. Could you provide more detail/specifics?  All I can do is copy some of your displayed values into a worksheet, and then import it into PQ, but this does not cause the errors you show.

Comment: Have you tried converting the .xls file to .xlsx or .csv? There's a history of odd issues with the .xls converter Power Query uses internally, to the point where I refuse to use .xls as a data source. I know a lot of crappy reporting systems out there still export to .xls, but there's plenty of ways to automate file conversion.

Comment: .xls was the problem, thank you